# How do i handle a large array in a react app?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am currently developing a webinterface for a camera system. I use the react framework and websockets for communication with the camera. I have to render an image to a canvas in serveral places in the app. The image data comes as an array containing brightness values for every pixel. Resolution is 800x600 so 480k array entries. I would like to store the last recieved image so I don't have to request a new one each time i render a canvas. I tried storing the array in the state of the App component but the ui got slowed down a lot. Any recommendations on how to store that data and access it from different places?

Comment: Do you know the byte size of the pixel values?

Comment: They are 8 bit 0-255 brightness values. They arrive at the websocket in form of a json string that gets parsed into a js object. I know that is stupid but it's not in my power to change it atm. Performace is not so bad though.

Comment: are you already storing the values in an ‘Uint8ClampedArray’?

Comment: No i just store the whole json data in a single object, containing additional information for each image as well as the raw image data.

Comment: Could you share your code, showing the `message` event handler, and where you call setState?

Comment: I have found a solution that works nicely for me. I am storing a numeric hash for every image in the appstate and the actual image data as a global object attached to document. When i need to access the image data, i use normal react techniques with the hash value and then access the associated image data using this hash directly in the component that needs the data.

Comment: very cool! I had a feeling that your image data would need to be stored outside of React state. But I wanted to see your code first. I'm glad that you were able to find a solution!